# How can I get intellisense to work for UDFs in XLAM files?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

I have some UDFs in an XLAM file.  Intellisense doesn't seem to pickup these UDFs when the XLAM is installed as an add-in.  The UDFs themselves work fine in Excel, its just that they don't appear in intellisense.  Here I mean intellisense when used on a worksheet.

Comment: Do you mean Intellisense in the VB editor, or when entering a formula on a worksheet?

Comment: Hi Tim - I mean entering formulas on a worksheet

Comment: Maybe try this link: http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/RegisterUDF01.asp which has an approach for XL2010

Comment: There is more explanation here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903587/the-quest-for-the-excel-custom-function-tooltip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There (is) was no way of getting a UDF (VBA, XLL etc) to supply intellisense. This has often been suggested to the Excel team as a worthwhile improvement.

(see https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2016/10/07/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-15-adding-intellisense-to-your-udfs/)

Answer (score 1):

With the Excel-DNA IntelliSense extension you can add in-sheet IntelliSense for your VBA-based UDFs (as well as .xll-based UDFs from Excel-DNA, PyXLL or one of the C/C++ toolkits).

The announcement and discussion of the IntelliSense extension is here: https://excel-dna.net/2016/11/24/excel-udf-intellisense-for-excel-dna-and-vba/

A detailed write-up on adding in-sheet IntelliSense to a VBA project (by Charles Williams) can be found here: https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2016/10/07/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-15-adding-intellisense-to-your-udfs/

Comment: I started using that just a few weeks after your post here. It is so great I feel it would deserve more attention and votes. In the meantime, since I realized I never came back here to vote, I corrected the situation.