# The quest for combining how to custom the Insert Function Wizard of a UDF and make the UDF manipulate other cells

Tags: vba, excel, debugging

This question may be of use for many VBA programmers. It involves implementing two useful independent tasks and making they work concomitantly.

The first task is making an Excel function tooltip for an UDF. Though a definitive solution seems to not have yet been found, for now I am satisfied with the solution of customizing the Insert Function Wizard. You can find the topic regarding the implementation of a way to customize the Insert Function Wizard here: [How to put a tooltip on a user-defined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262421/how-to-put-a-tooltip-on-a-user-defined-function)
 When I say Insert Function Wizard, I mean this window:

[image: Insert Function Wizard]

If you are also interested in the topic regarding the quest for finding a definitive solution for the implementation of a function tooltip, you can go here: [The quest for the Excel custom function tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903587/the-quest-for-the-excel-custom-function-tooltip)

The second task is making a UDF write in a different cell from which it was called. I have found a great solution for this task here: [I don't want my Excel Add-In to return an array (instead I need a UDF to change other cells)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520732/i-dont-want-my-excel-add-in-to-return-an-array-instead-i-need-a-udf-to-change)

Now, here comes the problem: **Excel crashes when trying to implement these two tasks concomitantly. I want to make these two tasks work when calling a single function, preventing excel from crashing**. I want to use a customized Insert Function Wizard for an UDF that can write in a different cell from which it was called. The reason for why I want to do this is that I am writing an AddIn with functions that take several input parameters (so the user need a tooltip for the input parameters) AND I need to write in cells different from the cell which they were called (because I do not want to stick to Macros. I want a function-driven AddIn and not a button-driven one). For those familiar with the Bloomberg Excel API, this is pretty much what the function BDH() does.

I wrote two modules as a guideline for the problem. The first one builds a displayParameters() function that needs to be run before running the main function. It executes through a function-driven way the task of customizing the Insert Function Wizard. The second function is the main function called sumTwoNumbers, which executes the sum of two numbers and displays the result in a cell different from the cell which the function was called. When you try to run the second function ( sumTwoNumbers() ) using the Insert Function Wizard ( ctr + A ), after it was customized ( after you have run displayParameters() ), Excel will crash.

Module 1:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" ( _
      ByVal HWnd As Long, _
      ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
      ByVal uElapse As Long, _
      ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long _
   ) As Long

Private Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" ( _
      ByVal HWnd As Long, _
      ByVal nIDEvent As Long _
   ) As Long

Private mCalculatedCells As Collection
Private mWindowsTimerID As Long
Private mApplicationTimerTime As Date

Public Function displayParameters() As Variant

' This is a UDF that returns true when the volscore file is created and starts a windows timer
' that starts a second Appliction.OnTime timer that performs activities not
' allowed in a UDF. Do not make this UDF volatile, pass any volatile functions
' to it, or pass any cells containing volatile formulas/functions or
' uncontrolled looping will start.

    displayParameters = "Success"

    'Cache the caller's reference so it can be dealt with in a non-UDF routine
   If mCalculatedCells Is Nothing Then Set mCalculatedCells = New Collection
   On Error Resume Next
   mCalculatedCells.Add Application.Caller, Application.Caller.Address
   On Error GoTo 0

   ' Setting/resetting the timer should be the last action taken in the UDF
   If mWindowsTimerID <> 0 Then KillTimer 0&, mWindowsTimerID
   mWindowsTimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, 1, AddressOf AfterUDFRoutine1_displayParameters)

End Function

Public Sub AfterUDFRoutine1_displayParameters()

' This is the first of two timer routines. This one is called by the Windows
' timer. Since a Windows timer cannot run code if a cell is being edited or a
' dialog is open this routine schedules a second safe timer using
' Application.OnTime which is ignored in a UDF.

   ' Stop the Windows timer
   On Error Resume Next
   KillTimer 0&, mWindowsTimerID
   On Error GoTo 0
   mWindowsTimerID = 0

   ' Cancel any previous OnTime timers
   If mApplicationTimerTime <> 0 Then
      On Error Resume Next
      Application.OnTime mApplicationTimerTime, "AfterUDFRoutine2_displayParameters", , False
      On Error GoTo 0
   End If

   ' Schedule timer
   mApplicationTimerTime = Now
   Application.OnTime mApplicationTimerTime, "AfterUDFRoutine2_displayParameters"

End Sub

Public Sub AfterUDFRoutine2_displayParameters()

' This is the second of two timer routines. Because this timer routine is
' triggered by Application.OnTime it is safe, i.e., Excel will not allow the
' timer to fire unless the environment is safe (no open model dialogs or cell
' being edited).

    Dim sumTwoNumbersArgumentsDescription(1 To 2) As String

    sumTwoNumbersArgumentsDescription(1) = "Write the first number of a Sum"
    sumTwoNumbersArgumentsDescription(2) = "Write the second number of a Sum"

    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="sumTwoNumbers", _
                         ArgumentDescriptions:=sumTwoNumbersArgumentsDescription
                         'Description:="describre the ivol function"

    MsgBox ("The formal parameters and instance of actual parameters are now successfully displayed at the Insert Function Dialog Box.")

End Sub
```

Module 2:

```
Option Explicit

'This global variable is the way I found of passing the output of sumTwoNumbers into the
'function "AfterUDFRoutine2"
Dim outputGlobal As Variant

Private Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" ( _
      ByVal HWnd As Long, _
      ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
      ByVal uElapse As Long, _
      ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long _
   ) As Long

Private Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" ( _
      ByVal HWnd As Long, _
      ByVal nIDEvent As Long _
   ) As Long

Private mCalculatedCells As Collection
Private mWindowsTimerID As Long
Private mApplicationTimerTime As Date

'Non-Volatile Function2
Public Function sumTwoNumbers(Optional ByVal param1 As Integer _
                    , Optional ByVal param2 As Integer _
                     ) As Variant

    sumTwoNumbers = param1 + param2
    outputGlobal = sumTwoNumbers
    sumTwoNumbers = "Success"

    'Cache the caller's reference so it can be dealt with in a non-UDF routine
   If mCalculatedCells Is Nothing Then Set mCalculatedCells = New Collection
   On Error Resume Next
   mCalculatedCells.Add Application.Caller, Application.Caller.Address
   On Error GoTo 0

   ' Setting/resetting the timer should be the last action taken in the UDF
   If mWindowsTimerID <> 0 Then KillTimer 0&, mWindowsTimerID
   mWindowsTimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, 1, AddressOf AfterUDFRoutine1_sumTwoNumbers)

End Function

Public Sub AfterUDFRoutine1_sumTwoNumbers()

' This is the first of two timer routines. This one is called by the Windows
' timer. Since a Windows timer cannot run code if a cell is being edited or a
' dialog is open this routine schedules a second safe timer using
' Application.OnTime which is ignored in a UDF.

   ' Stop the Windows timer
   On Error Resume Next
   KillTimer 0&, mWindowsTimerID
   On Error GoTo 0
   mWindowsTimerID = 0

   ' Cancel any previous OnTime timers
   If mApplicationTimerTime <> 0 Then
      On Error Resume Next
      Application.OnTime mApplicationTimerTime, "AfterUDFRoutine2_sumTwoNumbers", , False
      On Error GoTo 0
   End If

   ' Schedule timer
   mApplicationTimerTime = Now
   Application.OnTime mApplicationTimerTime, "AfterUDFRoutine2_sumTwoNumbers"

End Sub

Public Sub AfterUDFRoutine2_sumTwoNumbers()

' This is the second of two timer routines. Because this timer routine is
' triggered by Application.OnTime it is safe, i.e., Excel will not allow the
' timer to fire unless the environment is safe (no open model dialogs or cell
' being edited).

'Write the output to the sheet
Dim dest
Set dest = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
dest.Value = outputGlobal
Set outputGlobal = Nothing

End Sub
```

Progress so far

I have found that the Insert Function Wizard runs your function in the background after each time you fill an input parameter, and outputs the result after the '=' you see in the Wizard. Therefore, if there is an error that is triggered when you run your function with an insufficient number of parameters, that error will also be triggered after you provide the input in the Wizard. If a message box is displayed when you run your function with that number of inputs, a message box will be displayed in front of the Wizard. However, when you are using an UDF modified in order to write the output in a different cell from which it was called and no error is triggered when filling the inputs by the Wizard, excel will break. My guess is that this happens because your function runs in the background, triggering AfterUDFRoutine1_sumTwoNumbers(), then triggering AfterUDFRoutine2_sumTwoNumbers(). When AfterUDFRoutine2_sumTwoNumbers() finally tries to write in the excel Spreadsheet and the Wizard is open, excel breaks because you cannot write in a cell with the Wizard open. One obvious solution for this problem is finding a way to make the Insert Function Wizard stops running the function in the background after each input parameter is provided and make it wait till run the function after you click "OK".

Comment: tl;dr - Was there a question in all of this?

Comment: +1 for an interesting and thoroughly-researched question --- but you're trying to combine something that *all* the experts say literally cannot be done (tooltip in a UDF), with another functionality that nearly all experts say should never be done (using UDF to manipulate other cells).

Comment: Observed an unhandled error when AutoFill'ing this function `=sumTwoNumbers(1,3)` by dragging it down 5 or 6 rows in a column  which then causes Excel 2013 to crash.

Comment: While a tooltip in a UDF cannot be done, I am satisfied with customizing the Insert Function Wizard. However, I am indeed trying to combine these two functionalities. BDH() function from the Bloomberg Excel API does exactly what I am trying to do and works just fine. Can you provide me some material that explains why making a UDF manipule other cells should never be done?

Comment: When you say "Insert Function Wizard" is that simply the same as registering the function and including a description and description of the parameters?

Comment: Specifically, UDFs are *precluded* by design from performing most worksheet/range/object methods, see [here](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/oddity/a_user_define_function_cant_change_the_worksheet_oh_yeah/) for a few exceptions (there are more, IIRC) or see [this workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet) and also [here](https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50/excel-formula-to-change-the-value-of-another-cell) and [MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170787) for some background on the limitation.

Comment: Yes. It is a description of the function and a description of the parameters. It is the window that can be accessed by Ctr + A when you have '=function( ' written in a cell. I have edited the post in order to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

The question above was unnecessarily long. I could have summarized it by asking how to use the "Insert Function Wizard" in UDFs that are able to modify other cells. I had sticked to the concept of an UDF that could modify other cells as I knew it and did not think outside the box. The code of an UDF that can do that, as described here: [I don't want my Excel Add-In to return an array (instead I need a UDF to change other cells)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520732/i-dont-want-my-excel-add-in-to-return-an-array-instead-i-need-a-udf-to-change), breaks Excel when the user tries to use the "Insert Function Wizard". An workaround for this problem was to, instead of creating an UDF that modify external cells, was to create an UDF that auto-resize array outputs. I have found this Add-In: https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2014/08/25/self-extending-udfs-part-1/ which gives an implementation of a function called "=rxlRESIZE()" that resizes your array output. If you write that function inside your code, applying to your array output immediately before returning it, then you have an UDF that can write in other cells as long as your output is an array. Finally, this prevents Excel from crashing when you use the "Insert Function Wizard". For customizing the Insert Function Wizard, I am still using the implementation that I got from this post: [How to put a tooltip on a user-defined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262421/how-to-put-a-tooltip-on-a-user-defined-function)