# How I can show Tooltip on Excel Xll user defined functions?

Tags: c#, add-in, xll

I am having xll User defined function `=myfun()` in the excel cell.
How I can show the tooltip for excel xll function?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to do it, this is a known limitation of the Excel C API. See [The quest for the Excel custom function tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903587/the-quest-for-the-excel-custom-function-tooltip)