# Take augmented function inputs

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I have the following declared:

```
Public Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal X0_Y1 As Long) As Long
```

It grabs the monitor resolution.

So that in the future I remember to type 0 for x resolution and 1 for y resolution I have named the argument variable to illustrate that (`X0_Y1`). (So user can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> when entering the function to display its arguments)

But what I really want is to type "x" to get the x res and "y" for y res (i.e. `=GetSystemMetrics("x")` gives the x resolution). Is there a way to do this within the function decleration? Like `(ByVal iif(X0_Y1 ="x",0,1) As Long)` to specify what to do with the input.

I'd rather not just do this:

```
Function GetRes(letter As String) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    i = IIf(letter = "x", 0, 1)
    GetRes = GetSystemMetrics(i)
End Function
```

As it involves creating a whole new function which is more unweildy than just using the base one.
Perhaps there's some way to specify x/y as constants so that if the user enters them they are read as numbers not strings? Another nice option would be to get the input options displayed like the `Cell` function does. (Similar to [this question, but not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16903587/6609896))

[image: CELL function]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [Enum Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h84wky1.aspx) for this.

Declare an enum and your function like that

```
Public Enum MetricsType
    xMetrics = 0
    yMetrics = 1
End Enum

Public Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal xy As MetricsType) As Long
```

and you can use it like this

```
Dim x As Long, y As Long
x = GetSystemMetrics(xMetrics)
y = GetSystemMetrics(yMetrics)
```

This will also enable AutoComplete in the VBA editor.

---

To enhance the usability within the worksheet you can register/unregister your function as a UDF (user defined function). After registering you can select your function from the function menu and you see the comments within this dialog.

```
Sub RegisterUDF()
    Dim s As String
    s = "Some description here" & vbLf _
    & "GetSystemMetrics(<Metrics>)"

    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="GetSystemMetrics", Description:=s, Category:="My Category"
End Sub

Sub UnregisterUDF()
    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="GetSystemMetrics", Description:=Empty, Category:=Empty
End Sub
```

To get the enum working within the worksheet there is only workaround possible. Therefore you add a named range referring to `=0` or `=1` like below:

```
Sub RegisterEnum()
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="xMetrics", RefersToR1C1:="=0"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="yMetrics", RefersToR1C1:="=1"
    'NOTE: don't use x or y as names here as these refer to the column names. 
    'That's why I used xMetrics instead.
End Sub
```

Then you are able to use the function in your worksheet like `=GetSystemMetrics(xMetrics)`.

Creating the exactly same behavior like the built-in functions isn't possible as far as I know.

Comment: This is working when called with a `Sub` as you note, but not when called from the worksheet itself (as a cell formula). Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: As far as I know there is only a workaround like I added in the answer above. So you get a similar functionality but not exactly the same.